# Python: Web Scraping em página com valores dinâmicos

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Estou aprendendo sobre Web Scraping, Já consegui fazer algumas ações porém me deparei com problema em uma página dinâmica onde os valores são alterados a cada refresh.

Infelizmente não consigo passar a url de acesso por ser apenas interna, mas segue o código html da página, os valores de id e name se alteram constantemente, então pensei em pegar o dv, mas não obtive sucesso. Eu gostaria de dar um "tick" nesse radiobutton

```
<div class="clsCheckBoxRow"><
div class="dijitInline dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked">
    <input name="pOpt_N4eaf5820x6195143c_NS_" id="N4eaf5820x61951468_NS_" type="radio" role="radio" value="1" dv="Pesquisa por data de abertura (Criado em)" class="dijitCheckBoxInput" onclick="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onkeypress="return PRMTUtils.F_OnChange(event, this);" onfocus="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnFocus(this);" onblur="return PRMTUtils.f_CheckboxOnBlur(this);" aria-checked="false">
</div>
<label for="N4eaf5820x61951468_NS_" style="border: 0px none;">Pesquisa&nbsp;por&nbsp;data&nbsp;de&nbsp;abertura&nbsp;(Criado&nbsp;em)</label>
```

Segue o código que estou utilizando até o momento:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import base64
senha = b'criptografada'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\user\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('url-interna')
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

botao1 = browser.find_element_by_id('cmdOK').click()
time.sleep(2)

step1 = browser.find_element_by_name('CAMUsername').send_keys('teste')
time.sleep(2)

step2 = browser.find_element_by_name('CAMPassword').send_keys(base64.b64decode(senha).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
time.sleep(2)

botao2 = browser.find_element_by_id('cmdOK').click()
time.sleep(10)

# -*- código a ser implementado para extrais as informações do radiobutton*-
step3 = browser.find_elements(By.ID,'PRMT_SV*')[1]
print (step3)


time.sleep(5)
browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Comment: O nome e o id seguem algum padrão?

Comment: Eles seguem esse padrã com NS_ no final, mas por exemplo podem alterar todo o resto da string, ex:

 "N4eaf5820x61951468_NS_"
 "N5agh6870x61951468_NS_"
 "F6crhf8650x64551454_NS_"

E ssim por diante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo HTML fornecido, tente:

```py
step3 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.dijitInline.dijitRadio.dijitRadioChecked input').click()
```

Comment: Me retorna o erro: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Eu acabei de editar, talvez você não tenha pego o código atualizado.

Comment: Tiago ainda ocorre o mesmo erro:

 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: Você sabe me informar se este campo está visível na tela?

Comment: Tiago problema resolvido: step3 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.dijitInline.dijitRadio input').click()

Agradeço a tua ajuda !